# Javascript regular expression to search a string in word having multiple special characters (non space)

Tags: javascript, regex

Requirement is to find if the search string is present in the given string with below conditions.

**Condition 1** Search string should be found at the begin of the word i.e, no special characters preceding it.

- **abc** should match in string that begins with `abc` like `abcdef` any where in the sentence.
- **abc** should NOT match in `xabcdef` should NOT match as it is not starting with 'abc'

**Condition 2** If the string is preceded with some special character, then it should also have some text before special characters.

- **abc** should match in `test_abcdef` - as 'abc' is preceded with 'test_'
- **abc** should NOT match in `_abcdef` - as it is starting with '_' without any text before _

Below regular expression is not finding **abc** if string has **multiple** special characters ex in string `test@_abcdef` or `test__abcdef`.

In the regular expression not sure how to add quantifier in '**(?<=[A-Za-z0-9][^A-Za-z0-9])abc**' where **[^A-Za-z0-9]** is checking for SINGLE non alpha numeric character.

What is the syntax to add 0 or more special character in  reqex `(?<=... )`

**Regular Expression tried** in [Online Regex Tester](https://regex101.com/)

```
/^(?<![^A-Za-z0-9])abc|(?<=[A-Za-z0-9][^A-Za-z0-9])abc|(?<=\ )abc/g
```

**Sample Text :**

```
abcdef abcdef _abcdef xabcdef test_abcdef test__abcdef abc
```

Comment: Just like anywhere else : `(?<=(whateverHere)*)` `*` is for 0 or more.

Comment: @zenoo `(?<=([A-Za-z0-9][^A-Za-z0-9])*)abc` or `(?<=[A-Za-z0-9]([^A-Za-z0-9])*)abc` throws message: ** * A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width**, but does not match the pattern

Comment: Do you need capturing or just matching?

Comment: @anubhava, yes it needs to match in both condition.

Comment: @julio, it should match and will use exec and index to find the position to highlight the match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply all the assertions without alternation here:

```
/(?<![a-z0-9])(?<!^[^a-z0-9])(?<!\s[^a-z0-9])abc/igm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ptunIX/3)

This regex has 3 assertions before matching `abc`:

1. `(?<![a-z0-9])`: Fail the match when previous character is not alphanumeric
2. `(?<!\s[^a-z0-9])`: Fail the match when we have a non-alphanumeric character without preceding with some non-space character.
3. `(?<!^[^a-z0-9])`: Fail the match when we have a non-alphanumeric character at line start

Also note that lookbehind support in Javascript is still limited to new browsers only.

Comment: It is not matching (highlighting) any of the abc in regex101.com as there is some warning, for the regex

Comment: It says "Pattern error" (?: A lookbehind assertion has to be fixed width
) A lookbehind assertion has to be fixed width

Comment: If you click on this 2nd demo link: https://regex101.com/r/ptunIX/2 you will note how fast this regex is. This takes 169 steps as compared to 682 steps taken in accepted answer besides this regex also correctly matches `abc_abcabc`

Answer (score 0):

As regexes don't allow variable lenght lookbehind assertions, I don't think you can match just 'abc' but at the same time discard things like " _abc" " __abc" " ___abc", "____abc", etc.

I would suggest to do it in 2 steps:

First, try to match all required cases with a regexp without limiting yourself to just match 'abc'

```
(?:(?!abc[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)[a-zA-Z0-9]+[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+|^|\s)(abc)
```

https://regex101.com/r/bAo05D/3

Then, just recalculate abc index with: `abc_index = whole_regexp_index + length(regexp_matched_string) - length(abc)`

Comment: Updated to match abc_abc as index = 0